# Dealing with a huge collection of items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collections

In one of my application methods I'm dealing with a lot of entries that I have to save at the same time:

```
foreach (CategoryType category in apiCall.CategoryList)
{
    EBAY_CATEGORY itemToAdd = new EBAY_CATEGORY
        {
            CATEGORY_ID = int.Parse(category.CategoryID),
            CATEGORY_LEVEL = category.CategoryLevel,
            NAME = category.CategoryName,
            LEAF = category.LeafCategory,
            EXPIRED = category.Expired,
            VIRTUAL = category.Virtual
        };

    int? parentId = Int32.Parse(category.CategoryParentID[0]);

    if (parentId != null)
    {
        itemToAdd.PARENTID = parentId;
    }

    db.EBAY_CATEGORY.Add(itemToAdd);

    db.Entry(itemToAdd).State = EntityState.Added;

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

(Yup, I'm currently dealing with eBay). When this loop starts, I have downloaded up to about 20 000 items in a collection of complex items.

So you see that I have initiated a `foreach` to make sure that I save each of the entries in my database, but since it's a lot of operations it also take a lot of time. What would be the best way to deal with this collection of items?

**EDIT** So, following some very useful suggestions down below, here's my new code!

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    MyContext db = null;

    try
    {
        db = new MyContext();

        db.Database.Connection.Open();

        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

        int count = 0;

        ApiContext context = GeteBayApiContext();

        GetCategoriesCall apiCall = new GetCategoriesCall(context)
        {
            EnableCompression = true,
            ViewAllNodes = true
        };

        apiCall.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll);

        apiCall.GetCategories();

        foreach (CategoryType category in apiCall.CategoryList)
        {
            EBAY_CATEGORY itemToAdd = new EBAY_CATEGORY
            {
                CATEGORY_ID = int.Parse(category.CategoryID),
                CATEGORY_LEVEL = category.CategoryLevel,
                NAME = category.CategoryName,
                LEAF = category.LeafCategory,
                EXPIRED = category.Expired,
                VIRTUAL = category.Virtual
            };

            int? parentId = Int32.Parse(category.CategoryParentID[0]);

            if (parentId != null)
            {
                itemToAdd.PARENTID = parentId;
            }
            count++;
            db = AddToContext(db, itemToAdd, count, 2000, true);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    finally 
    {
        if (db != null)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }

    scope.Complete();
}
```

And the AddToContext method:

private static MyContext AddToContext(MyContext context,
                                             EBAY_CATEGORY itemToAdd, int count, int commitCount,

```
bool recreateContext)
{
    context.Set<EBAY_CATEGORY>().Add(itemToAdd);

    if (count%commitCount == 0)
    {
        context.SaveChanges();

        if (recreateContext)
        {
            context.Dispose();
            context = new MyContext();
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    return context;
}
```

It works fine and a lot faster, but each time the `Savechanges` method is called after a bulk of data has been inserted, I get the following error:

```
The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed.  The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.
```

This occurs after a bulk of 2000 data entries, or sometimes after a few shots of 100 data entries. I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `db.SaveChanges()` inside the loop and use db transactions.

You may get an OutOfMemory Exception if you have too many uncommitted changes as shown here [Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework)

So you would have to use modulo to `db.SaveChanges()` every x entries. Depends on how large your data is whether you need that at all.

Comment: That would speed up things that much?

Comment: For sure. It will allow the framework to batch insert data instead of firing one command after another to the database for each table entry.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I enfold everything in a whole transaction and call `db.SaveChanges()` after the scope has completed or right before?

Comment: Perfect answer can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework

Comment: Thanks for the information, that's a nice way of dealing with huge collections!

Comment: It does speed up things a lot, but I have a problem. I'll update the code above with the trouble. The following error : `The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed.  The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.` shows after a few savechanges.

Comment: Done up there, have a look. I have updated the code, there was a typo in it.

Comment: Did you try to increase the transaction timeout?
`using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new System.TimeSpan(0, 15, 0)))`

Comment: Nope, I can try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do database updates in batches to increase the speed. I am not sure which DB you are using here but most allow for fairly large batches.